# Apply single label image classification in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, image-segmentation

I am trying to apply single label image classification in Google Earth Engine in the context of Bragg Scattering. What I'm trying to do comes down to the following: Assign a single label (e.g. Bragg scattering present/Bragg scattering not present) to an entire image, and train a classifier to do the same (so 'this image contains serious Bragg scattering/this image does not contain serious Bragg scattering').

I've come across lots of examples for doing image classification with land cover, etc., but not one where the classifier in Google Earth Engine takes an entire image and assigns it a single label.

Are there any tips or examples of how to do this? I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find any examples of how to do so.